# In an Arduino project, what does it mean to be missing a primary expression before else?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I only started programming a few days ago and ran into a few problems.

I'm trying to make a servo turn 180 degrees when I type 1 and 180 degrees the other way when I type 0, I'm using an HC-05 Bluetooth module connected to my phone, so I tried to "merge" the servo sweep code from Arduino IDE library and another code that turns a light on by Bluetooth (which works), so I've been trying to fix this without any results.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
  #include <Servo.h>

  Servo myservo;

  int pos = 0;

  char data = 0; 

  void setup()
  {
  Serial.begin(9600); 

   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

   myservo.attach(13);
  }

  void loop()
  {
   if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {
  data = Serial.read();  

  Serial.print(data);  

  Serial.print("\n");  

  if (data == '1') for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) 


  else if (Serial.available() > 1)    

  digitalWrite(13, myservo(pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1));  
  }


  }
```

Arduino create keeps telling me I'm missing a primary expression before else.

Comment: please, take a codding course. and a Q&A site is not meant for "Can someone help me?" question

Comment: I suspect if braces and indentation were added to this, the problem could be identified.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the start of a `for` loop, but not told the compiler what operations to repeat.

When you're beginning, it's useful to add braces whenever you use a control statement (`if`, `while`, `for`, `do`, `switch`, `case`) irrespective of whether you have to, and indent consistently, then you can see where things should go and where the body of the control statement starts and ends.

```
void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {
        data = Serial.read();  

        Serial.print(data);  

        Serial.print("\n");  

        if (data == '1')
        {
            // execute the code from the 'sweep' example if the user sends '1'
            for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1)
            { 
                // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
                // in steps of 1 degree
                myservo.write(pos);       
                delay(15);
            }
        }
        else if (Serial.available() > 1)    
        {
            // removed as code here made no real sense   
        }
    }
}
```